# Confused about how can I handle several "Possible" exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, catch-all

I'm going to do something in C++, such as creating a file. In function which creates a file, I have set several exceptions for a possible failure. For instance if the file exists, if the disk is full, if the access is allowed, if the file creation ends happily etc...Now, when I want to catch them ALL, I get confused.

```
int file_create(std::string file_name) {...} // includes several exceptions at various points

try{
    file_create("/var/simple.txt");
}
catch(...){
   // what should I do here to have a specific control over what exception is throw?
}
```

I know `...` is for a catch-all, but I do not if it lets a deeper investigation of the exception thrown?

I compile based on the C++011.

Comment: `catch(SomeExceptionType &e){} catch(AnotherExceptionType &e){}` not working or something?

Comment: I just did not if we could have a sequence of catch(es). Can we?

Comment: Well.. did you try it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either do something like:

```
try
{
//your code
}
catch(FirstException &e){}
catch(SecondException &e){}
...
```

Or if you just want to catch some exceptions that are defined by you, you can create a custom `BaseException` and then define the others as subclasses of that one.